# Is it possible to position a JButton using coordinates?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I have been attempting to position a JButton but am having a lot of trouble. I need them to go at a very precise position, but have no idea how to achieve that. I've seen something called FlowLayout but I am very confused with it. I asked another question a couple of days ago on how to position a JButton and they gave me this fixed code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame
{
private JButton button1;
private JButton button2;

public Frame()
{
    button1 = new JButton("Hello button1");
    button2 = new JButton("Hello button2");
    button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    add(button2);
    add(button1);
}

}
```

and

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel
{
public static void main(String args [])
{
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't use ***FlowLayout()*** The class FlowLayout components in a left-to-right flow, make Layout(null) .

finally for **Button** You can use this

```
button1.setBounds(XPosition, YPosition, WidthOFButton, HeightOFButton);
```

Comment: So I do frame.setLayout(null); ?